# Want to make one column from rallygrid editable rally

Tags: extjs, extjs4, rally

Below is my code which display's a `grid`  using `rallygrid` that's all good but I want one `column` salary editable tried some suggestions but nothing worked for me.

I am using Rally sdk `/apps/2.0/sdk.js"`

```
        _draw_grid: function(newHash, committedData) {
                acceptedPoints = {};
                Ext.Array.each(committedData, function(cData){
                    if ( ! acceptedPoints[cData.ProjectName] ) { acceptedPoints[cData.ProjectName] = 0; }
                    acceptedPoints[cData.ProjectName] = cData.Accept;
                });
                summaryHash = {};
                _.each(projects, function(team) {
                    if (!summaryHash[team] && newHash[team]) {
                        summaryHash[team] = {
                            Name: team,
                            Count: newHash[team].length,
                            Days: 10,
                            Points: acceptedPoints[team],
                            Salary: "$200,000"
                        };
                    };
                });
                records = [];
                Ext.Object.each(summaryHash, function(key, value) {     
                    if (newHash[key]) {
                        records.push(value);
                    }   
                });
                this.records = records;
                var cfgsValues = [];
                cfgsValues.push({text: 'Teams', style:"background-color: #D2EBC8", dataIndex: 'Name', width: 170, renderer: function(value, meta_data, record, row, col) {
                    return value;
                }});                    
                cfgsValues.push({text: '# Developers', style:"background-color: #D2EBC8", dataIndex: 'Count', width: 70, renderer: function(value, meta_data, record, row, col) {
                    return value;
                }});
                cfgsValues.push({text: '# Points', style:"background-color: #D2EBC8", dataIndex: 'Points', width: 70, renderer: function(value, meta_data, record, row, col) {
                    return value;
                }});                    
                cfgsValues.push({text: '# Days in Sprint', style:"background-color: #D2EBC8", dataIndex: 'Days', width: 70, renderer: function(value, meta_data, record, row, col) {
                    return value;
                }});
                cfgsValues.push({text: '# Average Salary Cost per Sprint', style:"background-color: #D2EBC8", dataIndex: 'Salary', width: 100, renderer: function(value, meta_data, record, row, col) {
                    return value;
                }});                    
                this.setLoading(false);
                self.add({
                    xtype: 'rallygrid',
                    bodyBorder: 1,
                    showPagingToolbar: false,
                    showRowActionsColumn: false,
                    enableEditing:true,
                    editable: true,
                    selType: 'cellmodel',
                    plugins: [
                        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                            clicksToEdit: 1
                        })
                    ],                      
                    store: Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                        data: records
                    }),
                    columnCfgs: cfgsValues
                });             
            }               
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an editor to any columns that you want to be editable.

Try changing:

```
cfgsValues.push({text: '# Average Salary Cost per Sprint', style:"background-color: #D2EBC8", dataIndex: 'Salary', width: 100, renderer: function(value, meta_data, record, row, col) {
    return value;
}});
```

to

```
cfgsValues.push({text: '# Average Salary Cost per Sprint', style:"background-color: #D2EBC8", dataIndex: 'Salary', width: 100, renderer: function(value, meta_data, record, row, col) {
    return value;
}, 
editor: {
    xtype: 'numberfield' // this assumes that salary is a number; if not, set to 'textfield'
}});
```

Take a look at Ext JS's docs for Cell Editing to get a better idea of how to format your columns 
http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing

Comment: thanks @mcgrathg, still `numberfield` didn't work, but setting it to `textfield` worked. thanks a lot